# Program exiting when using String.ToUpper(); on a string that has spaces in it

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-core-3.1

Let me start off saying that I'm new to C#.

I'm currently in the making of my first command-line application that in it's current state can do two things. One of them is a calculator, for which I need more learning to actually make it work, and the other is a string capitalizer.

I have a `string nameCapInput = Console.Readline()` that takes in the user input, which then gets analyzed to make sure that no digits are allowed:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace First_Console_Project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My first ever console application - 2020/2/26\n\n\n");
        programSel:
            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?\n");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Calculate Numbers \n2. Capitalize Letters/Strings");
            Console.WriteLine("Input your desired action:");
            var inputVar = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (inputVar)
            {
                case "1":
                    //Calculator code goes here
                    Console.WriteLine("Number 1 succeeded, opening calculator... Stand by");
                    Console.WriteLine("Calulator Loaded.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't work right now. Type \"exit\" to get back to the \"what do you want to do\" page.");
                    //Code goes here when I have learned the proper methods
                calcInput:
                    var calcInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (calcInput == "exit")
                    {
                        goto programSel;
                    } else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Unknown command. Type \"exit\" to get back to the \"what do you want to do\" page.");
                        goto calcInput;
                    }
                case "2":
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading string capitalizer...");
                    Console.WriteLine("Type any string made of letters only without spaces, because if you use spaces, the program will exit. The output will make them all uppercase. Type \"exit\" to get back to the \"what do you want to do\" page.");
                inputCap:
                    string nameCapInput = Console.ReadLine();
                    bool containsInt = nameCapInput.Any(char.IsDigit);
                    bool isMadeOfLettersOnly = nameCapInput.All(char.IsLetter);
                    if (nameCapInput == "exit")
                    {
                        goto programSel;
                    }
                    else if (containsInt)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You can't capitalize numbers. Use letters only. Try again.");
                        goto inputCap;
                    }
                    else if (isMadeOfLettersOnly)
                    {
                        string upper = nameCapInput.ToUpper();
                        Console.WriteLine($"The uppercase version of your entered text is: {upper}");
                        goto inputCap;
                    }
                    break;
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

Now, everything works fine and it capializes everything I put into it **except** strings with spaces in them. When I type in a string with spaces in it, the program just exits with code 0. I'm not very good at C# yet, so I don't really know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Every time I learn something new in C#, I try to implement it into my projects, so I can actually learn how to implement it to know when and how to use what I learned. This is an example for that.

EDIT: Added the rest of the code.
Thank you all very much. There's two things I have learned here:

1. `goto` is a bad habit
2. I **absolutely** need to start learning to debug my own code.

Comment: First off, stop using `goto` entirely. It's not the 1980s.

Comment: Using `goto` is a habit you need to get out of right away.

Comment: When you have a space then isMadeOfLettersOnly will be false. You don't show the complete program so we don't know what happens if execution fall off the end of what is shown.

Comment: It bears repeating, get rid of `goto`

Comment: Wow, a lot of you are saying that ```goto``` isn't good. What should I use then?

Comment: @TimmSkiller loops, methods.  `goto` should _never_, **ever** be used

Comment: @TimmSkiller `goto` is a tool in your toolbox, but it tends toward low-quality spaghetti code.  Training yourself to write algorithms without it is very important.  `Gpto` should be considered the last option in development.  Google "goto considered harmful" for decades of commentary on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your problem is that you are *only* checking if the input contains letters (not spaces).  An easy fix is to change your LINQ a bit.

```
bool isMadeOfLettersOnly = nameCapInput.All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

So now input with letters *or* spaces will be considered valid.

In addition, your use of `goto` is a very bad idea.  Generally there should never be *any* reason to use `goto`.

To fix this, use a while loop and a method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool exit = false;
    do {
        exit = ProcessInput();
    }
    while(!exit);
}

private static bool ProcessInput()
{
    string nameCapInput = Console.ReadLine();

    bool containsInt = nameCapInput.Any(char.IsDigit);
    bool isMadeOfLettersOnly = nameCapInput.All(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c));

    if (nameCapInput.Equals("exit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        return true; //exiting so return true
    }
    else if (containsInt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You can't capitalize numbers. Use letters only. Try again.");
    }
    else if (isMadeOfLettersOnly)
    {
        string upper = nameCapInput.ToUpper();
        Console.WriteLine("The uppercase version of your entered text is: {0}", upper);
    }   
    return false; //no exit, so return false
}
```

This is just a quick refactor, you could make it better.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0g27Nv)

Comment: Thank you. The only thing I don't get is the `while(!exit);`. I haven't seen `while` used as a method. What does this do? It looks like it does something only when exit isn't true `!exit`.

Comment: @TimmSkiller thats a `do/while` loop, read into it.  Essentially means the `do` block will execute _at least once_ before checking the condition (`while()`).  So in your case it will ask the user for input, and if the input is `"exit"` it will return a true.  Since we are assigning the return value of `ProcessInput()` to the variable `exit` it will trigger the end of the loop because the variable will no longer be false.

Comment: That makes sense. Again, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter?view=netframework-4.8

Based on the documentation of the `IsLetter` function, the space is not included in the return true cases.

I would suggest that you use regular expressions for this or change your last case to

```
else if (!containsInt)
{
    var upper = nameCapInput.ToUpper();
    Console.WriteLine($"The uppercase version of your entered text is: {upper}");
    goto inputCap;
}
```

Also check the documentation of goto: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto

> The goto statement transfers the program control directly to a labeled statement.
>
> A common use of goto is to transfer control to a specific switch-case label or the default label in a switch statement.
>
> The goto statement is also useful to get out of deeply nested loops.

You are not in any such case, so you shouldn't use it.